# ajax login procedure - is using salt and hash is really neccessary?

Tags: ajax, security, http, logging

I'm sending password that user inputs to the server without obscuring it. I've read some suggestions to do the following before sending the data:

```
Ask the server for a seed value (a salt) using an ajax request
Hash the password + seed using a sha1 sum
```

Are these steps really enforce security in any substantial way? The salt isn't going to be unique so everyone can get it. The algorith of applying the salt is available to everyone as it is applied on a client. The algorithm of sha1 sum is also available so anyone can use it to unhash the password. So what's the benefit?

Comment: Please perform some cursory research on the topic - as to *why* passwords are hashed (and *what* hashing implies), *when* (and *where*) it's appropriate they are hashed, and *what* the purpose a salt serves and *why* salts should be "globally unique" (or, "very large random numbers").

Comment: Also, *don't* use SHA for password hashes. And, I don't feel confident about this "custom" handshake protocol - it just feels off to me; I know just enough about security to avoid the worst and trust (as in, defer to the protocols designed by) security experts. I would recommend HTTPS as the transport-level protection of the password.

Comment: Ah, that's why I don't like this approach: this requires that the server knows/stores the plain-text password (so it can generate the verification hash). I would rather have *an* account compromised than all my accounts compromised. The use of a fast-hash like SHA just rubs salt in the wound and does not "secure" the password over an insecure (HTTP) connection.

Comment: There is no easy way to "unhash" something, one needs to guess many passwords until the hash matches.

Comment: @user2864740, thanks for your comments! Why didn't you lay them as an answer? First of all, I've read a bit as you suggested and I now understand the difference between encrypted and hashed password. So my comment about unhashing a password doesn't make sense. Secondly, I don't keep users passwords in my DB as plain text - I hash them (I'll consider bcrypt (mcrypt for PHP) instead of SHA as you pointed out that I shouldn't use SHA). How does the approach described in the question require me to store plain-text? I can't send the hashed password to server for comparison

Comment: @StephanB, thanks! I now understand my misunderstanding :). However, [this article](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/) suggests that passwords hashed with standart (SHA-like algorithms) can be now cracked pretty easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know these steps ([Digest auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication)) the salt is unique for every session, so every login attempt will get its own, different salt. Please consult your sources if it is the case there, too.

The client, after reading the salt for the current login process and sends the hash of the password+salt to the server wich compares it to its own hash of password+salt.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll definitely read it through. If this _sends the hash of the password+salt to the server_ suggests that a client sends hashed password, why does `user2864740` states that this approach requires server to store plain-text passwords?

Comment: For every salt (nonce in the link) the hash must be calculated so the server cannot store the hash in advance. Like the client it needs to know the plaintext to check the hash.

Comment: I see, thanks. So what are the alternatives to `digest auth`? I don't want to store plain text in my database. HTTPS?

Comment: Yes, HTTPS + Basic auth (sending passwords to the server unmodified) is a valid alternative.

Comment: Thanks, any other? :) I don't think HTTPS is an option for me right now. I guess I'd better stick with basic auth + hashing using bcrypt + globally unique salt.